# Check if command line arguments are palindrome words using Threads

Tags: c, pthreads, palindrome

Write a program that receives as arguments words. For each word from command line it creates a thread which checks if the word is palindrome. If the word is palindrome, it increments a global variable (in thread).

This is what I did:
It's not working because the types are not compatible in function palindrome. What can I do? Can I pass the command line arguments in other way (not by using myStruct) ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int var_global = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mtx; 
typedef struct{
    char* word;
}myStruct;

int palindrome(myStruct aux){
    int k = strlen(aux);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<k/2; i++) {
        if(aux[i] != aux[k-i])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

void* f(void* w){
    myStruct aux;
    aux=*(myStruct*)w;

    if (palindrom(aux)==1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        var_global++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     int i;
     pthread_t threads[argc];
     pthread_mutex_init(&mtx, NULL); 

     myStruct s[argc];
     for (i=1;i<argc;i++){ 
        s[i].word = argv[i];
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, f, &s[i]);
     }

     for (i =1; i<argc; ++i)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

     printf("the global variable has the value: %d \n", var_global);
     pthread_mutex_destroy(&mtx);

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you ever allocated memory for the strings you are using?  ( `s[i].word = argv[i];` ) where `char* word;` is a member of struct myStruct

Answer (score 1):

Did you steal code from 2 different programs and tried to smash them together or what?

gcc says:

> /usr/include/string.h:395:15: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘myStruct’

Although threading code is terrible, the person who wrote it would likely know what to do here.

But I'm in a good mood today, so:

```
int var_global = 0;
```

It is already zero. Terrible non-descriptive name.

```
pthread_mutex_t mtx; 
typedef struct{
    char* word;
}myStruct;
```

Terrible spacing.

```
int palindrome(myStruct aux){
```

Why? How about just passing the string?

```
int k = strlen(aux);
```

Clearly, strlen takes a const char *, not 'myStruct'.

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<k/2; i++) {
```

Terrible spacing. Preferably would be: "for (i = 0; i < k/2; i++) {".

```
    if(aux[i] != aux[k-i])
```

Incorrect. Let's consider string "crap". strlen is 4, thus referring to an element with index 4 gives us the terminating '\0'. As such you always compare the first element with the terminating '\0'.

```
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

void* f(void* w){
    myStruct aux;
    aux=*(myStruct*)w;
```

Why the excessive copying? How bout myStruct *aux = w;

```
    if (palindrome(aux)==1){
```

Why the explicit comparison? Pass only the string.

```
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
        var_global++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
    }
}
```

Missing return statement.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     int i;
     pthread_t threads[argc];
```

Incorrect. Let's consider an invocation with 1 argument. This gives argc 2 and the table is oversized.

```
     pthread_mutex_init(&mtx, NULL); 

     myStruct s[argc];
```

Same here.

```
     for (i=1;i<argc;i++){
```

Terrible spacing, also inconsistent with previous terrible spacing.

argc should be decremented and this loop should start from 0.

```
        s[i].word = argv[i];
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, f, &s[i]);
```

Missing error checks.

```
     }

     for (i =1; i<argc; ++i)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

     printf("the global variable has the value: %d \n", var_global);
     pthread_mutex_destroy(&mtx);

     return 0;
}
```